# SAX Parser does not display multiple identical tags

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

Previously, I was able to display the data of one tag, but this time not several values are displayed, but only one.

This my parser code:

```
public class Runner {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
    MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);

    xmlReader.parse("src/countries.xml");
    Countries branches = handler.getBranches();

    try (FileWriter files = new FileWriter("src/diploma/SAX.txt")) {
        files.write("Item " + "\n" + String.valueOf(branches.itemList) + "\n");
    }
}

private static class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler{
    static final String HISTORY_TAG = "history";
    static final String ITEM_TAG = "item";

    static final String NAME_ATTRIBUTE = "name";

    public Countries branches;
    public Item currentItem;
    private String currencyElement;

    Countries getBranches(){
        return branches;
    }

    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        currencyElement = qName;

        switch (currencyElement) {

            case HISTORY_TAG: {
                branches.itemList = new ArrayList<>();
                currentItem = new Item();
                currentItem.setHistoryName(String.valueOf(attributes.getValue(NAME_ATTRIBUTE)));
            } break;

            default: {}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        String text = new String(ch, start, length);

        if (text.contains("<") || currencyElement == null){
            return;
        }

        switch (currencyElement) {

            case ITEM_TAG: {
                currentItem.setItem(text);
            } break;

            default: { }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException{
        switch (qName) {

            case HISTORY_TAG: {
                branches.itemList.add(currentItem);
                currentItem = null;
            } break;

            default: {
            }
        }
        currencyElement = null;
    }

    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("SAX parsing is completed...");

    }
}
}
```

Class Item:

```
public class Item {

private String historyName;
private String item;

public String getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(String item) {
    this.item = item;
}

public String getHistoryName() {
    return historyName;
}

public void setHistoryName(String historyName) {
    this.historyName = historyName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return
            "historyName = " + historyName + ", " + "\n" + "item = " + item + ", ";
}
}
```

And class Countries

```
public class Countries {

   public List<Item> itemList;
}
```

I have problems with this part

```
  <history name="История">
    
        <item>
            История белорусских земель очень богата и самобытна. 
        </item>
        
        <item>
           Эту страну постоянно раздирали внутренние конфликты и противоречия, много раз она была втянута в войны.
        </item>
        
        <item>
            В 1945 году Беларусь вступила в состав членов-основателей Организации Объединенных Наций.
        </item>
    
    </history>
```

I only display the last "item" tag, and other duplicate tags are displayed only in the singular. I can't figure out where the error is, but I noticed that in "endElement" all values are displayed, but as one element. Maybe someone knows what's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new ArrayList every time you encounter the item tag.
That is why you only see one item displayed after parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help. I decided to switch to XmlPullParser, it solved my problem.